# When will Azure Data Catalog Gen2 go GA?

Tags: azure-data-catalog

Information on this seems impossible to come by, though it seems clear it will not be until at least 2021.  I do mean GA and not public preview.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding service general availability, we don't have ETA. I would suggest to keep an eye on [Azure updates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?category=analytics&query=Data%20Catalog).

Azure updates provide information about important Azure product updates, roadmap, and announcements

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as an answer( click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.